# Is there something like ignore_below for text type in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am storing some text in elastic search (type: "text") and would like elastic to ignore words that are shorter than 3 chars. So, for instance, if I have a sentence "A car with an add", I would like elastic to store it like `["car", "with", "add"]`, instead of `["a", "car", "with", "an", "add"]`. Is there an option like this?

Bellow is my index mappings, I would like the "publication" to have the above mentioned option:

```
mappings: {
    properties: {
        publication: {
            type: "text",
            fields: {
                keyword: {
                    type: "keyword"
                }
            }
        },                
        published: {
            type: "date",
            fields: {
                keyword: { 
                    type: "keyword"
                }
            }
        },
        id: {
            type: "text"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [length token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-length-tokenfilter.html). Use the below index mapping, tokens which are less than 3 characters will be ignored

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "standard_length": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "length_3_char"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "length_3_char": {
          "type": "length",
          "min": 3
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "standard_length"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Tokens generated will be

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "standard_length",
  "text" : "A car with an add"
}
```

Tokens are

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "car",
      "start_offset": 2,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "with",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "add",
      "start_offset": 14,
      "end_offset": 17,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @ljerka please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify what you wrote - so I have to add the "settings" part when creating an index and add the "analyzer": "standard_length" on the object that I would like to use that specific analyzer. All other objects in my index mapping (in which I don't add the "analyzer": "standard_length") will be analyzed with words shorter than 3 chars? @ESCoder

Comment: Exactly @ljerka. You need to add an analyzer to all those fields in which you want that tokens should not be generated of less than 3 characters. Please try this, and let me know if this gives you the desired result?

Comment: Yes, it works like a charm :) And now, with this code, I can see how easy it is to do other filters. Thank you, I accepted your answer.